# Error al crear una nueva venta

Tags: django

Estoy realizando un sistema con Django el cual tiene productos, clientes y ventas. La idea es crear una venta (la cual puede tener uno o más detalles de venta), elegir el cliente, la fecha, el metodo de pago y los productos que se quieran vender.

[image: Imagén del formulario]

El problema es que, cuando le doy a registrar venta me sale el siguiente error:

```
SaleDetail has no product.
```

Y la verdad no estaria entendiendo por que me sale. Les dejo la vista:

```
class CreateSaleView(CreateView):
model = Sale
form_class = SaleForm
template_name = 'sales/create.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('sales:list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    sale = form.save()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    for product in products:
        quantity = self.request.POST.get(f'product-quantity-{product.pk}')
        if quantity is not None and quantity != '':
            quantity = int(quantity)
            if quantity > 0 and quantity < product.stock:
                quantity = int(quantity)
                sale_detail = SaleDetailForm()
                sale_detail.sale = sale
                sale_detail.quantity = quantity
                sale_detail.product = product
                sale_detail.save()


                product.stock -= quantity
                product.save()

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me falto poner .save(commit=False) cuando creaba el formulario